# Why is it printed as 'run time error signal -1' when function findFirstZero returns -1 here?

Tags: java, function, return, runtime

When i give the following input via stdin:

4
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

It throws 'run time error signal -1' instead of printing 'No Zeros'

Why is this happening ?
I have used online Ideone compiler to run the code.

```
class FindZeroCount
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        //sc.nextLine();
        int input[]=new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            if(sc.hasNextInt())
                input[i]=sc.nextInt();
            else
                System.out.println("Not enough inputs given");

        int zi=findFirstZero(input,0,size-1);
        if(zi==-1)
            System.out.println("No zeros");
        System.out.println("Number of zeros = "+ (size-zi));

    }
    public static int findFirstZero(int input[],int l,int h)
    {
        int mid;
        if(h>=l)
        {
            mid=l + (h-l)/2;
            if((mid==0 || input[mid-1]==1) && input[mid]==0)
                return mid;
            else if(input[mid]==1 && input[mid+1]==0)
                return mid+1;
            else if(input[mid]==1)
                return findFirstZero(input,mid+1,h);
            else
                return findFirstZero(input,l,mid-1);

        }
        return -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run your code through your debugger step by step? What did you find?

Comment: When I run your program and paste input 4 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 It gives me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. by the way, What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to count the no of zeros in an array containing only 1s and 0s sorted in descending.. I corrected the 3rd condition to 'if(input[mid]==1 && (mid==input.length-1 || input[mid+1]==0))' and it works fine now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when running the code with input as stated in your question: On your third recursive call you have `l = 3`, `h = 3` and thus `mid = 3`. When the code enters your second if-statement (`else if(input[mid]==1 && input[mid+1]==0)`) you are trying to access index number 4, but your array's index only goes from 0 to 3.

Try stepping through your code with the debugger: Put a break point at the line `int zi=findFirstZero(input,0,size-1);` and step through it line by line!

*However, I was not able to enter the entire sequence of numbers you gave above, since your first number (i.e. 4) tells how many numbers you can enter. When I enter 4 as the first number the code will start evaluating the sequence given after I enter the fourth 1.*

Comment: Thank you so much.. I changed the condition like this 'if(input[mid]==1 && (mid==input.length-1 || input[mid+1]==0))' and it works fine now...